# python re: search and findall give different results

Tags: python, search, python-re, findall

why do search and findall give different results?

```
result = re.search(r'Bat(wo)?man', 'The Adventures of Batman')

print(result) # found

re.findall(r'Bat(wo)?man', 'The Adventures of Batman') # empty list
```

Comment: findall finds it, too, as demonstrated by the **non**-empty list you got.

Answer (score 2):

When I run this, I don't get an empty list, but a list containing a single empty string: `['']`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (emphasis mine):

> The result depends on the number of capturing groups in the pattern. If there are no groups, return a list of strings matching the whole pattern. **If there is exactly one group, return a list of strings matching that group.** If multiple groups are present, return a list of tuples of strings matching the groups. Non-capturing groups do not affect the form of the result.

You use a capturing group (`(wo)?`), so the results only contain the part of the string that matched that group.

You can fix this by changing the group to a non-capturing group:

```
>>> print(re.findall(r'Bat(?:wo)?man', 'The Adventures of Batman'))
['Batman']
```